# Modal with AJAX in Bootstrap and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I've read several other threads with the same question but I dont manage to find my mistake.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.orderdetails').click(function(){

            var userid = $(this).data('id');

            // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {orderid: orderid},
            success: function(data){ 
                // Add response in Modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(data);

                // Display Modal
                $('#OrderDetails').modal('show'); 
            }
            });
            });
            });
    </script>
```

This script tag runs on the same page as the modal, the modal looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="OrderDetails" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Order Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the output of the ajax.php I'm getting a clean html, even tried deleting all and just putting an **echo "test string";** (at this point I'm not using the post variable, just want to make it work) and get the modal to popup but with no content. Also tried putting all the output ajax.php inside a variable called response and replacing (data) for (response) in the jquery with no luck.

EDIT:

My ajax.php content

```html
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://danielacevedo.com/store-sandbox',
    'KEY',
    'KEY2',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2'
        
    ]
);


try {

 $details = $woocommerce->get('orders/94');
 $query = ['date_min' => '2017-10-01', 'date_max' => '2025-10-30'];

 $lastRequest = $woocommerce->http->getRequest();
 $lastRequest->getUrl(); // Requested URL (string).
 $lastRequest->getMethod(); // Request method (string).
 $lastRequest->getParameters(); // Request parameters (array).
 $lastRequest->getHeaders(); // Request headers (array).
 $lastRequest->getBody(); // Request body (JSON).

 $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
 $lastResponse->getCode(); // Response code (int).
 $lastResponse->getHeaders(); // Response headers (array).
 $lastResponse->getBody(); // Response body (JSON).
}

catch(HttpClientException $e) {
 $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
 $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
 $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
}

?>


             <div class="container">
                              <h2 class="sub-header">Order detail</h2>
                                <div class='table-responsive'>
                                    <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th>Order #</th>
                                                <th>Customer</th>
                                                <th>Address</th>
                                                <th>Contact</th>
                                                <th>Order Date</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Actions</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php 

                echo "<tr><td>";
                
                foreach($details->shipping_lines as $shipping_details){
                    if ($shipping_details->method_id == 'local_pickup'){
                        echo "<i class='fas fa-store-alt'></i>";
                    }
                    if ($shipping_details->method_id == 'flat_rate') {
                        echo "<i class='fas fa-motorcycle'></i>";
                    }
                    else {
                        
                    }
                }

                echo "</td>";
                echo "     <td>" . $details->id ."</td>
                          <td>" . $details->billing->first_name . " " . $details->billing->last_name ."</td>
                          <td>" . $details->shipping->address_1 ."</td>
                          <td>" . $details->billing->phone ."</td>
                          <td>" . date("jS F, Y g:i a", strtotime($details->date_created)) ."</td>
                          <td>" . $details->status ."</td>
                          </tr>";
                ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(data);` in your success callback and check what it actually contains. You can also check the network tab in your browsers web tool to see the request and the actual response for the ajax request.

Comment: Added, nothing in console when I open the modal.

Comment: Then check the network tab as mentioned above. Can you please post the PHP code you have in `ajax.php` as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson In the network tab I don't get anything other than the initial page load. I edit the question to add my ajax.php content. (removed the keys intentionally, when you browse to the ajax file you see valid html with the table)

Comment: You need to have the network tab open when you make the ajax request. The request should then show up there. If it doesn't then it doesn't seem to make a request.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it end's up being a simple writting error... I forgot to add the trigger class to the button... I feel dumb haha.. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

More easy ;-)

```
<script>
$(function(){

   $('.orderdetails').click(function(){

   var userid = $(this).data('id');

   // AJAX request
   $.post( 'ajax.php', {orderid: orderid}, function(data){ 
   // Add response in Modal body
   $('.modal-body').html(data);

   // Display Modal
   $('#OrderDetails').modal('show'); 
});
</script>
```

You need more option to use model with 
                 with data-dismiss="modal"